# Select Case Multiple When Select Conditions Gives Error

Tags: sql, subquery

The code below works fine.

```
 (SELECT        (CASE 
  WHEN (PA.ACTOR_KIND = 5) THEN
     (SELECT   POP.KDS_TEKLIF_TUT_TL) 
      ELSE 0 END) AS Expr1) AS YKF_CUSTOMER_LIMIT
```

However,when I add another "when" condition it gives error.

```
 (SELECT        (CASE 
  WHEN (PA.ACTOR_KIND = 5) THEN
     (SELECT   POP.KDS_TEKLIF_TUT_TL)
  WHEN (PA.ACTOR_KIND = 10) THEN
     (SELECT   POP.KDS_ALICI_LIM_TL) 
      ELSE 0 END) AS Expr1) AS YKF_CUSTOMER_LIMIT
```

It seems all logical to me but not for sql

**Edit It was caused by  typo error,there is nothing wrong with those statements.

Comment: What is the error?  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Also, please use a readable format. That alone might show you the error (e.g. missing parantheses, mismatching `case`/`end` etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this will fix your problem, but you don't need `SELECT` for the `WHEN` clauses:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN PA.ACTOR_KIND = 5
             THEN POP.KDS_TEKLIF_TUT_TL
             WHEN PA.ACTOR_KIND = 10
             THEN POP.KDS_ALICI_LIM_TL 
             ELSE 0
        END) AS YKF_CUSTOMER_LIMIT
```

You don't need to give the expression a name in the subquery as well as in the outer query.  One name is enough.  (Although that doesn't cause your error.)

Comment: Althought,It didn't cause error ,It doesn't need a expression and select statement , I changed my code and removed unnecessary selects and expr.

Comment: @erhan355 . . . I see.  That is not an error, just unnecessary.

Comment: I accept your answer to avoid other responses to this question and for your effort to show best practices.